# Using awk to process a mapping file with dynamic number of columns

Tags: awk, gawk

I am wondering how to process information as following:

`mapping.txt`:

```
80  001 002
81  011 012 013 014
82  021 022
...
```

`input.txt`:

```
81  103823044
80  103823054
81  103823064
...
```

Desired `output.txt`:

```
103823044|011|
103823044|012|
103823044|013|
103823044|014|
103823054|001|
103823054|002|
103823064|011|
103823064|012|
103823064|013|
103823064|014|
```

I've done simple mapping wherein the column numbers are fixed but I'm unsure of how to map a dynamic number of columns to the desired output

Comment: Is using `awk` a requirement, or do you have the option of using a different language that might make this easier?

Comment: You have changed your input but have not updated your output.  What output do you expect from the example files you gave us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { x[$1,$2] = $1; next; } { for (i in x) { if (x[i] == $1) { split(i,t,SUBSEP); for (z = 2; z <= NF; z++) { print t[2] "|" $z "|"; } } } }' input.txt mapping.txt
```

The first block is executed while reading the file `input.txt`. It is achieved by condition `NR == FNR` which is `true` while the first file is read. In the first block we create an array `x` with keys from first ans second column and values from first column. The second block is executed for the file `mapping.txt` because of `next` in the first block. In the second block we check for every key in array `x` if value from column 1 exist as value in array `x`, and if exists extract second part of the key with `split` and we print in a loop this value and values from second column till last column (`NF` - number of fields in current record).

Comment: Since the OP is a self-proclaimed `awk` newbie, could you explain a little about how this would work?

Comment: @roaima, sorry, I'll edit it.

Comment: This works if the first column in the input file is unique, but it's not... I've updated my question to reflect that change

Comment: @K- answer edited.

Comment: excellent, works like a charm... thanks! I did not know you could do multi-dimensional arrays with awk! This is great!!